# リリースノートについて

Tags: realm

Realmを初めて使用します。
過去のバージョンについてのリリースノートを確認したいのですが、リリースノートはどこから閲覧可能でしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

それぞれのライブラリの CHANGELOG.md 等に書かれています。たとえば [realm/realm-cocoa](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa) では [CHANGELOG.md](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md) ないし [release ページ](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/releases)に書かれています。